# Can't Edit Geolocation field in Sharepoint List

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-list

In Sharepoint, I am trying to create a map view from a sharepoint list. To do this, I am following [this guide](https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2016/12/sharepoint-online-powershell-to-add-geolocation-bing-maps-field-to-list.html) (which mirrors the documentation).  I had no problems running the powershell....

```
Add-PnPField -List $List -Type GeoLocation -DisplayName $FieldName -InternalName $FieldName -AddToDefaultView -AddToAllContentTypes
```

... and I can see the geolocation field in the site settings:

[image]

The problem is that I can't edit the value in the list.  It doesn't work in "Create", "Edit" or "Edit in Grid".  If I click on the column in site settings, there is no option to make it editable.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could try Add a list item with the Geolocation field value to a SharePoint list programmatically:
After the Geolocation field is added to a SharePoint list, the developer can add the list item to the list programmatically. There are two ways to add the list item programmatically: by passing the FieldGeolocationValue object to the Geolocation field, and by passing Raw Value to the Geolocation field.
Reference:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/how-to-add-a-geolocation-column-to-a-list-programmatically-in-sharepoint#add-a-list-item-with-the-geolocation-field-value-to-a-sharepoint-list-programmatically

Comment: Thank you for the response, it is greatly appreciated!  Just to be clear, this would mean that any and all updates to the list would have to be done via code?